# Node.js and Socket.io not working on this Example

Tags: jquery, node.js, socket.io

Can you please take a look at following code and let me know what I am doing wrong on that? Running Node.js + Express + Socket.io on Ubuntu 12.4 I am trying to create a simple Push function. The server is working perfectly but I cant see the div id "status" content on the page and apparently the function is not running!

Thanks for your help and comment in advance and sorry for long post!

Here is the **app.js** file
    /**
     * Module dependencies.
     */

```
 var express = require('express')
 , routes = require('./routes')
 , user = require('./routes/user')
 , http = require('http')
 , path = require('path');

 var app = express();

 // all environments
 app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
 app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
 app.set('view engine', 'jade');
 app.use(express.favicon());
 app.use(express.logger('dev'));
 app.use(express.bodyParser());
 app.use(express.methodOverride());
 app.use(app.router);
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

 // development only
 if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
   app.use(express.errorHandler());
  }

  app.get('/', routes.index);
  app.get('/users', user.list);

  var status = "I am not changed yet!.";

  io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  io.sockets.emit('status', { status: status }); 
  socket.on('reset', function (data) {
  status = "You Change the text!";
  io.sockets.emit('status', { status: status });
  });


 http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
 console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
 });
```

I modified the "**package.json**" as below, adding the sockt.io to dependencies

```
{
  "name": "application-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
  "start": "node app.js"
  },
 "dependencies": {
 "express": "3.2.3",
 "jade": "*",
 "socket.io:0.9.14"
  }
 }
```

in the **view** folder and in **index.jade** I have

```
<div id="status"></div>
<button id="reset">Reset!</button>
```

and in **layout.jade** What I have is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Title</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML elements -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- styles -->
<link href="/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
<%- body %>
<script src="node_modules/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="public/js/libs/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="public/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

and Finally this the function which I have in **main.js**:

```
var socket = io.connect(window.location.hostname);
socket.on('status', function (data) {
$('#status').html(data.status);
});

$('#reset').click(function() {
socket.emit('reset');
});
```

error Message after editing by robert Hint

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:901:3
```

Comment: look at the browser console, does this script successfully loaded: node_modules/socket.io/socket.io.js? from the socket.io doc, this should work:<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a few basics: you're not loading the `socket.io` module (I'm assuming you did install it, otherwise use `npm install socket.io` first), you're not connecting it to the HTTP server, and you're not including the client in your template properly (as @ltebean already pointed out).

Server side first:

```
// app.js
var express = require('express')
,   routes  = require('./routes')
,   user    = require('./routes/user')
,   http    = require('http')
,   path    = require('path');

var app     = express()
,   server  = http.createServer(app)               // create HTTP server
,   io      = require('socket.io').listen(server); // load socket.io and connect      
                                                   // it to the HTTP server
...

// start listening
server.listen(app.get('port'));
```

Client side next:

```
// layout.jade
...
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
...
```

In your `main.js`, I would suggest using `io.connect` auto-discovery:

```
var socket = io.connect(); // no argument means auto-discovery
```

Also, you `package.json` is invalid:

```
"socket.io:0.9.14"     // not a valid object property!
"socket.io" : "0.9.14" // should be this
```

Comment: Also, in the html file he needs to create a '<div id="status"></div>' element, so that his client code can access/update it.

Comment: Hi Robert Thanks for you comment but after editing the files to what you said I am getting this error now.Please take a look at end of the first post i just edited

Comment: @BehrouzHosseiniK. I just noticed: your templates look like [ejs](https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs), which is completely different from [jade](http://jade-lang.com/), the templating engine you have configured. You need to either convert your templates to Jade, or use the EJS engine (and since EJS doesn't support layouts, you'll need [ejs-locals](https://github.com/RandomEtc/ejs-locals) as well).

Comment: Ok! I am really really LOST! Can you please let me know how I can set ejs! Thanks again

Comment: @BehrouzHosseiniK. it's explained on the [ejs-locals page](https://github.com/RandomEtc/ejs-locals), including some simple examples.